# What is json interface parameter in mycontract?

Tags: web3js

in web3.js , to define a new contract

```
new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface[, address][, options])
```

so what is jsonInterface and where can i find it?
Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the ABI(Application Binary Interface). You can compile your source code from [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org). On the compilation screen, you'll see a button to get the ABI. Click it to copy the ABI. That's what you need.

[image]